# Multilabel Classification with Scikit Learn and Probabilities Instead of Simple Labels

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification

I'd like to classify a set of 3d images (MRI). There are 4 classes (i.e. grade of disease A, B, C, D) where the distinction between the 4 grades is not trivial, therefore the labels I have for the training data is not one class per image. It's a set of 4 probabilities, one per class, e.g.

```
0.7   0.1  0.05  0.15
0.35  0.2  0.45  0.0
...
```

... would basically mean that

- The first image belongs to class A with a probability of 70%, class B with 10%, C with 5% and D with 15%
- etc., I'm sure you get the idea.

I don't understand how to fit a model with these labels, because scikit-learn classifiers expect only 1 label per training data. Using just the class with the highest probability results in miserable results.

**Can I train my model with scikit-learn multilabel classification (and how)?**

Please note:

- Feature extraction is not the problem.
- Prediction is not the problem.

Comment: Is your intent to predict classification of an image in any of the four classes, or rather "search" the probabilities defined elsewhere? What is your input data - image data itself, or some meta information on images? Where do the probabilities (labels on your data) originate from?

Comment: I tried to formulate the setting in general, hoping that this would make it easier. But if that really helps, I can provide the following concretization: The input data are 3d scans of brains - but my problem is **not** how to calculate the relevant features (you call it meta information). The intention is to predict (four) probabilities that an 3d MRI belongs to (disease) class A, B, C and D. The distinction between the 4 classes is not trivial, therefore my labels are only probabilities (classified by doctors). The four probabilities will sum up to 1.0.

Comment: Is there a per-image unique and correct/best assignment of labels to these images? It seems to me you that in calculating probabilities for the four classes and using these as labels, you are essentially doing the work of the classifier. If you can use the classes A, B, C, D as labels, the predict_proba method will return a probability for each class for any given new input.

Comment: You should probably send these probabilities as added features with along with highest class labels, and then see the results of predict_proba, if it changes anything. Anyways, as its defined now, the question is not suitable for stack-overflow. Please add this to https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: How are the probabilities that you want to use as labels  derived? Also you state _prediction is not the problem_. Maybe you don't need a machine learning algorithm but a search algorithm?

Comment: Since the values to be predicted are probabilities, one could possibly view this as a [multioutput regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-regression) problem. So instead of predicting class labels, you would predict the probability of each class.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310828/multilabel-classification-with-scikit-learn-and-probabilities-instead-of-simple/310885#310885

Answer (score -1):

> Can I handle this somehow with the multilable classification framework?

For `predict_proba` to return the probability for each class A, B, C, D the classifier needs to be trained with *one* label per image.

> If yes: How?

Use the image class as the label (`Y`) in your training set. That is your input dataset will look something like this:

```
F1  F2  F3  F4  Y

1   0   1   0   A
0   1   1   1   B
1   0   0   0   C
0   0   0   1   D
(...)
```

where `F#` are the features per each image and `Y` is the class as classified by doctors.

> If no: Any other approaches?

For the case where you have more than one label per image, that is multiple potential classes or their respective probabilities, multilabel models might be a more appropriate choice, as documented in [Multiclass and multilabel algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).

Comment: No, this is not the case. The OP clearly states that he had tried this with miserable results. He wants something in which he can pass the probabilities of all predicted labels. And then get the probabilites as result.

Comment: I reformulated the question, it shouldn't be "too broad" anymore. Would you please consider to re-activate it?

Comment: @VivekKumar in order for predict_proba to return the class probabilities of the four classes A,B,C,D the classifier needs to be trained with _one_ class label per image. That's how this inherently works. In the case where there are multiple labels or multiple discrete values the multilabel classifier approach is not applicable anymore. That's all my answer states.

Comment: I understand that completely. What I am saying is, the OP knows this and have tried that. He has supplied single label to the classifier and taken predict_proba() output, but the results are not good. What he wants is to somehow take the training label dependencies into consideration in form of previous probabilities. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: I fully agree with @VivekKumar
Meanwhile I did further research on the topic and could answer this question - if it was not still **on hold**.
Basic idea: The labels are not independent and therefore I simply replaced the classes by combinations of classes - with quite good results.